# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) on macos

Tags: c++, macos-catalina

I am practicing a simple c++ code base on example

```
class Tset{
    public:
        Tset();
        Tset operator+( const Tset& a);

};

Tset Tset::operator+(const Tset& a){
    Tset t;
    return t;
}
```

but when I use g++ to compile this code 
it occur this error

```
Mac Desktop % g++ hw2.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Tset::Tset()", referenced from:
      Tset::operator+(Tset const&) in hw2-43d108.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

here is my g++ version:

```
Mac Desktop % g++ -v     
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: The output tells you exactly what the problem is: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`. Did you try searching this site for that error message?

Comment: @KenWhite I did , but I only found something different with my situation....

Comment: It's not *different with your situation*. The problem is the same as every other of those posts. You don't have the right libraries specified or they're not available.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your suggestion , I will try to find a good material...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not provided a definition of the constructor.

This function is implicitly calling `Tset::Tset()`, the constructor:

```
Tset Tset::operator+(const Tset& a){
    Tset t;    // Requires definition of constructor.
    return t;
}
```

But in your class, you do not define the constructor:

```
class Tset {
public:
    Tset();            // No definition.  :-(
    Tset operator+(const Tset& a);
};
```

You can fix this by providing a definition of the constructor, or *defaulting* the constructor:

```
class Tset {
public:
    Tset() = default;
    Tset operator+( const Tset& a);
};
```

Comment: oh....how  silly mistake it is... Thank you so so much ! Originally I thought it is the problem of  g++  enviroument...